# Unable to extract TXT file from zip and convert to Dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, zip

I wrote a webscraper that will download a zip file of the information I need.  I have been able to locate the correct file (Incident.txt), but I have been unable to convert it to a Dataframe with pandas.

So far I have tried

```
with zipfile.ZipFile(latest_file, mode='r') as archive:
 archive.extract("Incident.txt", path ='c:')
df= pd.read_csv('c:\Incident.txt')
```

Which raised an invalid argument error.

and

```
with zipfile.ZipFile(latest_file, mode='r') as archive:
 data=archive.read("Incident.txt").decode(encoding='utf-8')
df= pd.read_csv(data)
```

Which just printed the whole CSV file in the window.

Any ideas?

Comment: read_csv is used to read csv file, which is not your case. My best bet is reading your file with readlines, and convert your list into a dataframe or convert your txt into a csv with your favorite tool

Comment: The file is listed as a .txt but it has CSV in it.  If I manually do the file import from the path, it works fine.

Comment: Did you try to modify `df` in your `with` indented block ?

Comment: No,  the df is outside the with block.  Its the first time I call df in the program.